# How to tell whether a collection exists in MongoDB using Mongoid?

Tags: collections, mongodb, mongoid

Since `Mongoid.master.collection()` returns a collection even if the collection doesn't exist, we can use

```
coll = Mongoid.master.collection('analyticsCachedResult')
if coll.count == 0
  # [...]
end
```

to test if it is an empty collection.  Another method is to loop through

```
Mongoid.master.collections.each do |c|
  return c if c.name == 'analyticsCachedResult'
end
return nil
```

but is there a simpler way to detect whether it exists?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure how to do it through Mongoid, but in general you can query the *system.namespaces* collection for `{name : "dbname.analyticsCachedResult"}`.

Comment: ah, thanks for the hint.  This line works too: `Mongoid.master.collections.map {|c| c.name}.include? 'analyticsCachedResult'` although if Mongoid has such a call it may be better.

Answer (score 1):

Using the mongo ruby driver, I extended the DB class:

```
class Mongo::DB
  def collection_exists?(collection_name)
    x = "#{self.name}.#{collection_name}" # e.g., "redbike_db.clients"
    nil != self['system.namespaces'].find_one({'name' => x})
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For the gem `mongoid (8.0.2)`, I use this code

```
client = Mongoid.default_client
current_db = client.database

current_db.collection_names.include?("name of the collection you want to check")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [`Mongoid::Findable#exists?`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid%2FFindable:exists%3F)

- `exists?` will evaluate `true` if at least there is one document in the collection...

Let's assume this is your model:

```rb
class AnalyticsCachedResult
  include Mongoid::Document

  store_in collection: "analyticsCachedResult"

  class Foo
    include Mongoid::Document
    embedded_in :analytic_cached_result, inverse_of: :foos, class_name: "AnalyticsCachedResult"
  end

  embeds_many :foos, class_name: "AnalyticsCachedResult::Foo"
end
```

- where `Foo` is embedded in the analytics document

While both models can refer to a collection, that does not mean they will generate a collection each:

```rb
AnalyticsCachedResult.collection.name
# => "analyticsCachedResult"

AnalyticsCachedResult::Foo.collection.name
# => "analytics_cached_result_foos"
```

So when there are no documents yet, `exists?` it will return `false`

```rb
AnalyticsCachedResult.exists?
# => false

AnalyticsCachedResult::Foo.exists?
# => false
```

Now let's create one document and persist it:

```
acr = AnalyticsCachedResult.new
acr.foos.build({})
acr.save!
```

Your top model will now evaluate `true`:

```
AnalyticsCachedResult.exists?
# => true
```

And although there is one `AnalyticsCachedResult::Foo` document, it is stored *embedded in* `AnalyticsCachedResult`, and therefore its collection will be empty:

```
acr.fooes.first
# => #<AnalyticsCachedResult::Foo _id: 111122223333444455556666, >

AnalyticsCachedResult::Foo.exists?
# => false
```